# Tealium && Robolectric

Tags: android, robolectric, tealium

Problem with [Tealium](https://github.com/tealium/tealium-android) if we use robolectric all over.

We have our UnitTest without calling methods from  [Tealium](https://github.com/tealium/tealium-android)  successfully.
However, there're crash at all tests if we use it.

We have ShadowApplication in tests.

```
java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 50
Exception Details:
  Location:
    com/tealium/library/Tealium$Config.<init>(Landroid/app/Application;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V @10: ifnull
  Reason:
    Expected stackmap frame at this location.
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 2ab7 007d 2a2b 5ab5 004d c600 282a 2c5a
    0x0000010: b500 4eb8 006b 9a00 1c2a 2d5a b500 4fb8
    0x0000020: 006b 9a00 102a 1904 5ab5 0050 b800 6b99
    0x0000030: 000d bb00 2c59 120a b700 7cbf 2abb 001a
    0x0000040: 59b7 0064 120f b600 6912 14b6 0067 1215
    0x0000050: b600 652a b400 4eb6 0065 2ab4 004f b600
    0x0000060: 652a b400 50b6 0065 1212 b600 6512 1312
    0x0000070: 0db6 0066 120e b200 37b6 0066 1210 1208
    0x0000080: b600 66b6 0068 b600 63b5 0056 2abb 002a
    0x0000090: 59b2 0060 1204 1008 bd00 2d59 032b b600
    0x00000a0: 6153 5904 b200 5fb8 007b 5359 05b2 005f
    0x00000b0: b800 7b53 5906 2c53 5907 b200 5fb8 007b
    0x00000c0: 5359 082d 5359 1006 b200 5fb8 007b 5359
    0x00000d0: 1007 1904 53b8 007f b700 79b5 0054 2ab4
    0x00000e0: 0054 b600 7a57 2abb 0034 59b7 0087 b500
    0x00000f0: 532a b200 48b5 0057 2a04 b500 582a 04b5
    0x0000100: 0059 2ab2 0049 b500 5a2a b200 4ab5 005d
    0x0000110: 2ab2 004c b500 5b2a b200 4bb5 005c 2abb
    0x0000120: 0034 59b7 0087 b500 522a 2ab4 0054 b800
    0x0000130: 77b5 0051 2abb 001e 592a b400 4d2a b400
    0x0000140: 50b7 006c b500 55b1
```

https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/3709

Comment: Does this help? https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/2750

I work in the Tealium Devices team (mobile SDKs). I think this is something we may be able to change in the SDK build process, but that thread may help you solve the issue in the meantime.